# In Oracle SQL, Add max values (row by row) from another table when other columns of the table are already populated

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables A and B. Table B has 4 columns(ID,NAME,CITY,COUNTRY), 3 columns has values and one column (ID) has NULLS. I want to insert max value from table A column ID to table B where the ID field in B should be in increasing order.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC1rd.png)

```
TABLE A
ID      NAME
------- -------
231     Bred
134     Mick
133     Tom
233     Helly
232     Kathy

TABLE B
ID      NAME    CITY       COUNTRY
------- ------- ---------- -----------
(NULL)  Alex    NY         USA
(NULL)  Jon     TOKYO      JAPAN
(NULL)  Jeff    TORONTO    CANADA
(NULL)  Jerry   PARIS      FRANCE
(NULL)  Vicky   LONDON     ENGLAND
```

ID in column in B should be populated as MAX(ID) +1 from table A. The output should look like this:

```
TABLE B
ID     NAME     CITY       COUNTRY
------ -------- ---------- -----------
234    Alex     NY         USA
235    Jon      TOKYO      JAPAN
236    Jeff     TORONTO    CANADA
237    Jerry    PARIS      FRANCE
238    Vicky    LONDON     ENGLAND
```

Comment: Is it a one time operation or a Regular one?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Text is preferred instead of images as it's easier to copy & paste, and some people can't access images. Also it's best to focus on a specific technical issue that you're having trouble with.

Comment: Regular one. If it is a one time operation what would you suggest? @CaiusJard

Comment: @WilliamRobertson- Thank you for the note. I have added text

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest method is to create a one-time sequence for the update:

```
create sequence temp_b_seq;

update b
    set id = (select max(id) from a) + temp_b_seq.nextval;

drop sequence temp_b_seq;
```

You could actually initialize the sequence with the maximum value from `a`, but that requires dynamic SQL, so this seems like the simplest approach.  Oracle should be smart enough to run the subquery only once.